# Swift Can't Find xlsx path returns nil

Tags: swift, database, excel, null

I am working on creating a simple survey mobile application to learn how to use excel as a starter database. I followed the GitHub project on xlsxreaderwriter and built the project after completing each step and it was successful.

Now I am in my Viewcontroller trying to get my Xcode project to show me the cells I suggested in my console but instead the system returns an error stating:**"Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"**

My code is the following:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  xlsxreaderwriter
//
//  Created by Ahmeeya Goldman on 1/29/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 Ahmeeya Goldman. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //Set the path to the path of the excel file you are accessing

        let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DatabaseV1", ofType: "xlsx")!


        //Open the spreadsheet, get get the first worksheet, and select cell B5

        let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
        let sheet: BRASheet = spreadsheet.workbook.sheets[0] as! BRASheet
        let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
        let cell: BRACell = worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "B5")

        // Print some info to show the code works
        print(sheet.name) // print "sheet1"
        print(cell.stringValue()) // print 0
        print("Test Worked, Excel Launch Didn't")
    }
}
```

Comment: What line is causing the error?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. The following code is causing the error: let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "DatabaseV1", ofType: "xlsx")!

Comment: Then your xlsx file isn't in your app's bundle. Make sure it is added to your project and properly targeted.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem.

My file is in the "Downloads" folder and from there I drag and drop the file into my project. In the pop-up window, I click "Finish", but the PRINT function gives us an empty path (this can be seen in the screenshot below right).
[First screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YokTv.png)

Okay, why? This is because the project added a link to the file, not the file itself.

When you drag and drop a file into your project, in the opened window you need to put a tick in the "Add to targets" item on your project. This can be seen from the [second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhPUH.png). At the bottom right you can see that the path to the file is defined.